# Removing parent slug in hierachial custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I need to remove the parent slug in the permalink of a child post. The child post is of a different cpt than the parent post. So I get:

```
example.com/parentcpt/parent-post-name/child-post-name //which results to a 404.
```

I need

```
example.com/child-post-name
```

or:

```
example.com/childcpt/child-post-name
```

Switching between permalink structures doesnt help either. 
Ive tried a number of plugins but they dont solve.
Adding the following doesnt help:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => false, 'with_front' => false)// register_post_type function
```

Someone help please ... :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the code below under my theme/functions.php file. (My custom post type slug is 'news')

```
            function df_custom_post_type_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {  
                $post = get_post($id);  
                if ( is_wp_error($post) || 'news' != $post->post_type || empty($post->post_name) )  
                    return $post_link;  
                return home_url(user_trailingslashit( "$post->post_name" ));  
            }
            add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'df_custom_post_type_link' , 10, 2 );
            function df_custom_rewrite_rule() {
                add_rewrite_rule('(.*?)$', 'index.php?news=$matches[1]', 'top');
            }
            add_action('init', 'df_custom_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: Is there a way to alter this for multiple custom post types? (So more than just 'news')?